# How to use System.out.printf to allign output by the "middle"

Tags: java, printf

I'm getting desired output (output is aligned in vertical line around first "1.0"):

```
heaviside(1.0) = 1.0
  sigmoid(1.0) = 1.0
```

but code seems ugly to me.

```
System.out.printf("%10s%.1f) = %.1f","heaviside(", x, x);
System.out.printf("%10s%.1f) = %.1f","sigmoid(", x, x);
```

is it possible do not pass `"heaviside("` and `"sigmoid("` as argument but include it in formatted string somehow?

```
System.out.printf("heaviside(%10s%.1f) = %.1f", x, x);
```

does not compile cuz lacking of third argument

```
System.out.printf("heaviside(%.1f) = %.1f", x, hX);
System.out.printf("sigmoid(%.1f) = %.1f", x, x);
```

produces the output aligned by left like this:

```
heaviside(1.0) = 1.0
sigmoid(1.0) = 1.0
```

Comment: Remove `%10s`, then required arguments will be 2. `System.out.printf("heaviside(%.1f) = %.1f", x, x);`

Comment: it produces the output alligned by left like this:
```
    heaviside(1.0) = 1.0
    sigmoid(1.0) = 1.0
```

Comment: the problem is not with line break but with allignment. i'm just struggling with puting multiline code in comment to show the indented and actual output

Comment: oh, I get what you mean. alignment spaces. as for that, I'm not sure.

Comment: @sittsering
just added explanation why it does not suit to initial question

Comment: You can use the `String` `format` method to format Strings before outputting them.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your sample:

`System.out.printf("%10s%.1f) = %.1f", "heaviside(", x, x);`

You are formatting 3 arguments:

- 1º argument is formatted as text with fixed space of 10 chars, aligned to right;
- 2º and 3º arguments are formatted as a number with fixed 1 decimal place;

**You question is:** *"is it possible **to not pass** "heaviside(" and "sigmoid(" **as argument** but include it in formatted string somehow?"*

To maintain text spacing, using your fixed string aproach, you need to turn this into the formatting string, like this:

```
System.out.printf("heaviside(%.1f) = %.1f", x, x);
System.out.printf("  sigmoid(%.1f) = %.1f", x, x);
```

As noted by @sittsering, you need to note that you removed an argument on format string, so you need to remove corresponding input argument.

---

You also comment that *"but code seems ugly to me"*. Yes, this code is ugly, but your requested change do not make it better. Code is ugly because it is mixing arguments with format:

- `%10s%.1f)`: here you put closing parenthesis in format;
- `heaviside(`: here you put opening parenthesis in input argument.

A better approach would be something like this:

`System.out.printf("%10s(%.1f) = %.1f", function, x, x);`

---

Now, observe that this alignment will not work with numbers with mixed sizes, like 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, ...

If this is a problem, to solve this, you can use fixed size with numbers formatting too.

Comment: you've just put trailing spaces before   `sigmoid` in your solution. And my question was how to assure allignement by row of first numbers in every string of output, giving that that number is preceed by the rows names with different lengths

Comment: @Ignat, yes, I just put fixed trainling spaces, and I really do not recommend using this. But here I write 1 snippet of code that directly answer your question: "is it possible do not pass 'heaviside(' and 'sigmoid(' as argument but include it in formatted string somehow?". Saying that I do not answer another question is not polite.

Comment: Also, @Ignat, note that I gently added 1 more snippet in second part of answer. If none of theses snippets fulfill your requirements, please, rewrite your question to better expose your needs.